# Installing virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, virtualenv

I installed Python 3.7.1 using home-brew, and on the command line typing `python` returns the default python 2.7.10 and `python3` gives the home-brew installed version. Then using

`python3 -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib`

I installed the required packages. 
Now what I understand is that to use the home-brew version python I have to always use `python3`and the required packages are installed inside python 3's lib folder.

I want to install virtual env correctly. I want to know what command should I use if I want it to be usable with python3?

Comment: Do it the same way you did for numpy, scipy and matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install virtual env because [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module is included in Python 3 standard library.

To create a virtualenv under `.venv` subdirectory of the current working directory:

```
 python3 -m venv .venv
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you want to create python3 environments. First install virtualenv using pip.
`pip install virtualenv`
Then you can create a python3 environment like this:
`virtualenv -p python3 env_name`